# AWK one liner to merge three fields in a single file

Tags: awk, columns, merge

I have a file with records (lines) having two types of field delimiters `|` and `!` as given below:

```
Name|Age|Physics|Chemistry|Maths|English|Batch!Year!AdmisnNo!Grade!Score
Student1|81|65|70|80|88|EWS!2021!1001!A!75
Student2|72|63|60|50|75|EWS!2021!1002!A!85
Student3|72|63|60|50|75|EWS!2021!1002!A!85
```

How to merge `Batch`, `Year` and `AdmisnNo` fields as given below?

Note, for brevity I have shown a small list of useful fields, where as my real files have many such related fields. This field where I want to remove two or three `!` marks is not the last one and can be any field (6 or 7 ) from a total number of fields around 49.

```
Name|Age|Physics|Chemistry|Maths|English|BatchYearAdmisnNo!Grade!Score
    Student1|81|65|70|80|88|EWS20211001!A!75
    Student2|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
    Student3|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
```

I requested `awk`, however any reasonably standard command is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { sub("!", "", $NF); sub("!", "", $NF) }; 1' file
Name|Age|Physics|Chemistry|Maths|English|BatchYearAdmisnNo!Grade!Score
Student1|81|65|70|80|88|EWS20211001!A!75
Student2|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
Student3|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
```

This uses `awk` to delete the first two `!` characters from the last `|`-delimited field of the input.

Use any number in place of `NF` in the `awk` code to affect some other field than the last field.

---

Assuming only the last field contains `!` characters, using `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed -e 's/!//' -e 's///' file
Name|Age|Physics|Chemistry|Maths|English|BatchYearAdmisnNo!Grade!Score
Student1|81|65|70|80|88|EWS20211001!A!75
Student2|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
Student3|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
```

This removes the first `!` on each line.  It then performs exactly the same substitution a second time, removing the second `!` too.

---

Reversing each line and removing the 3rd `!` twice in a row, then reversing the resulting line again.  This allows other `|`-delimited fields to also contain `!` characters.

```bsh
$ rev file | sed -e 's/!//3' -e 's///3' | rev
Name|Age|Physics|Chemistry|Maths|English|BatchYearAdmisnNo!Grade!Score
Student1|81|65|70|80|88|EWS20211001!A!75
Student2|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
Student3|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
```

Comment: Thanks @kusalananda is it possible to select field from first say 6th field with | delimiter.  Is is possible to remove either two or three ! marks. Please help and appreciate your time for helping

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety You appear to be changing the question.

Comment: I have a list of such files and are quite unorganised, from various sources, my question is to select a   | delimited  field which has subfields ! and merge them. If possible kindly help me.

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety This is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks I am running awk one liner.  Thanks for the support.

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety regarding `my question is to select a | delimited field which has subfields ! and merge them` - that is definitely not the question you asked. You asked about `a file with records (lines) having two types of field delimiters | and !` and how `to merge three fields`, not a file that has 1 type of delimiter (`|`) but where each field could have sub-fields delimited by `!`s and how to merge some of those subfields within a field - that's a very different situation and you should ask a new question about THAT if that's what you really have.

Comment: What is the difference between `s/\([^!]*\)!/\1/` and a simple `s/!//`?

Comment: @Philippos There is absolutely no difference. I probably had too many other things to think about yesterday.  Thanks, I will update my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat in | while read -r line ; do line="${line/\!/}" ; echo "${line/\!/}"; done
Name|Age|Physics|Chemistry|Maths|English|BatchYearAdmisnNo!Grade!Score
Student1|81|65|70|80|88|EWS20211001!A!75
Student2|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
Student3|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
```

Comment: Thanks @JdeHaan Where can I modify thi sscript If I want to remove three ! marks

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety If you have clarifications to your question, then please update your question.  Note that you have three answers that are actually solving your issue as stated, though.

Comment: Thanks once again replacing within echo is new thing I have learnt.

Comment: See http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html and [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

This task is good for `sed`, without splitting fields, to merge the 7th field with the next one:

```
sed -E 's/|\|!//7' file
```

Running once more will merge the 7th (initially the 8th) with its next one. Totally:

```
sed -Ee 's/|\|!//7' -Ee 's/|\|!//7' file
```

Or more shortly (suggested by Philippos), as the second substitution will happen if the first did:

```
sed -E 's/\||!//7;s///7' file
```

Also `-E` is used for portability, meaning for extended regular expressions.

Output:

```
Name|Age|Physics|Chemistry|Maths|English|BatchYearAdmisnNo!Grade!Score
Student1|81|65|70|80|88|EWS20211001!A!75
Student2|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
Student3|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
```

Note that after the first substitution, the 8th field became 7th, so we use `7` again for it. It's the same like doing `sed '' file | sed ''`.

Also it is convenient about the different field separators you have here, and can be adjusted for merging almost any neighboring fields.

Comment: (1) I don't know that syntax, it seems like you expect `\|` as alternation symbol like `|` in extended regular expressions. To stay portable, you can use `sed -E 's/\||!//7'`. (2) Instead of repeating a pattern, better use an empty pattern to make visible that there is nothing new: `sed -E 's/\||!//7;s///7'`

Comment: @Philippos I like (2), the second empty expr is evaluated to true again when the previous one was true. And yes, the man page also includes -E for portability for EREs but I never  include it, I 'll update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for the 4th arg to `split()`:

```
$ awk '{n=split($0,f,/[|!]/,s); s[7]=s[8]=""; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", f[i], s[i]; print ""}' file
Name|Age|Physics|Chemistry|Maths|English|BatchYearAdmisnNo!Grade!Score
Student1|81|65|70|80|88|EWS20211001!A!75
Student2|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
Student3|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
```

Comment: This a good demo for the `split()` ability to handle the array of separators. And it scales for field numbers and separators.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for above example and got desired output

```
sed -e 's/!//1' -e 's/!//1' file.txt
```

output

```
Student1|81|65|70|80|88|EWS20211001!A!75
Student2|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
Student3|72|63|60|50|75|EWS20211002!A!85
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's just one possible perl solution

```
perl -pe '@a = split /[|!]/; $_ = join "|", @a[0..5], join("!", join("", @a[6..8]), @a[9,10]);' file
```

written with a series of `join`s that so if your use case gets more complicated, say you want to drop Maths, you just drop that index (4)

```
perl -pe '@a = split /[|!]/; $_ = join "|", @a[0..3,5], join("!", join("", @a[6..8]), @a[9,10]);'
```

It seemed neater than concatenating fields and splicing the extra fields out of the array before joining back together.